# Cannot pop a viewcontroller back to the UITabView in my storyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I was having memory management issues, finally found out the problem, I keep instantiating new view controllers. When the app launches it goes straight to the `FirstViewController` which is an element inside of `UITabBarController` in the storyboard.

I then show `FilterViewController` with this method:

```
- (IBAction)searchOptions:(id)sender {
    FilterViewController *ctrl = [[FilterViewController alloc] init];
    [UIView transitionFromView:self.view toView:ctrl.view duration:1 
          options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp completion:nil];

    self.filterViewController = ctrl;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.filterViewController 
          animated:NO];
}
```

Which works fine and brings up `FilterViewController` which has its own .xib, so it is **not** in the storyboard.

Now when trying to pop back to `FirstViewController` I use this method:

```
- (IBAction)backToMap:(id)sender {

    // i used the below when trying to push another view controller
    /*UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName
        :@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];

    FirstViewController *fvc = [storyboard 
        instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FirstViewController"];

    fvc.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;*/

    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

However it doesnt do anything. Nothing at all, I cant see what is wrong here?

Comment: that `transitionFromView:toView:duration:options:completion:` call looks totally wrong in there. Remove it and see what happens.

Comment: @MatthiasBauch hey thanks for the comment, removed it and the button doesnt open a viewcontroller now

Comment: then FirstViewController is probably not part of a navigationController. Check if `self.navigationController` is nil. If it is you have to wrap your FirstViewController in a UINavigationController

Comment: @MatthiasBauch I have put it in an NSLog and it is coming up as `(null)` so, how can I wrap this in a navigationController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

popViewontrollerAnimated is only used when you have pushed your view controller onto a navigation stack, so it won't do anything here unless there is one in your project.

When you use transitionFromView... you are **replacing** your current view with the new view so you will need to call it again to get back to your old one.

Comment: So there is in fact nothing wrong with the way I am doing it? Is there a more memory efficient way?

Comment: Well, you have some extra calls in your searchOptions method.  Since you won't be returning to this view controller, only the first two calls are needed.  Memory should be fine though.